# XSLT or library to convert Open XML to RTF in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, rtf

How can I convert Open XML to RTF in c#?
I could use just an xslt to convert, just wandering if there is one already available or if there is a .net library that can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are aware but there is an XSLT to convert Word Open Xml to Html called

> DocX2Html_IE.xslt
>   https://openxmlviewer.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Source/OpenXMLViewer/DocX2Html_IE.xslt

Which is part of the [OpenXML Document Viewer](https://openxmlviewer.codeplex.com/) on codeplex. I've used this style sheet as a guide to creating my own Word to Html parser in c#, as I'm not a fan of giant XLST. It's not complete by any means but might help you as a starting point for creating a RTF xslt.

As a side note this project has not been updated since 2009